# PHPMyAdmin unable to execute queries, no response

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

In my table, I have about 300,000 records. Sometimes I do queries in PHPMyAdmin, it doesn't do anything. No errors or no table record shown. I'm not sure if it is my table is too big or some configuration problem. I tried to use the "Search" in PHPMyAdmin and it still doesn't response.

I tried to run this query, and it didn't do anything:

```
UPDATE `openhourz`.`ohz_business` 
SET `catConvert` = 1 AND `main_category_id` = '18' 
    AND `sub_category_id` = '248' 
WHERE `ohz_business`.`categories` ='Japanese, Noodles';
```

Help!

Comment: what is your table name in `openhourz`.`ohz_business` ?

Answer (score 0):

must be like this one:

```
update mytable set mycolumn1='data 1',mycolumn2='data 2' where name='john'
```

so the seperator between 2 column is `,` not a `and`.

hope this useful for your problem.

Comment: dont forget,the phpmyadmin that actualy run on browser have the execution time.